# Lenovo Y50-70 dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, lenovo

I purchased a Lenovo Y50-70 (**i7-4710HQ, 8GB DDR3 RAM, 4GB N16P-GX DDR5 Graphics Card and 1TB SSHD(8GB)**) earlier this week. It has only Windows 10 installed as of now and there is only 1 partition.

**I was told by the shopkeeper that Windows 10 allows only 3 partitions maximum**, exceeding which, the hard drive will be corrupted. Is it true? I was on a Windows 7 machine before this and it had a C: for Windows 7, a D:, an Ubuntu MATE 15.10 partition and a swap partition - making it 4 partitions. If the 3 partitions rule is true, does that mean that in order to dual boot, I would have to sacrifice the D:? Please help.

Also, since I was on a Windows 7 machine before this, I did not have to deal with this UEFI nonsense to worry about. With Windows 10, turns out I need to. Now, there is a sea of tutorials for dual booting Linux with Windows 10, but I'm not sure which one to follow. Could anyone here please help find a **single reliable source that I can follow end to end and get my Ubuntu up and running**?

Thank you.

Comment: Test doing dual boot on a virtual machine (e.g.: virtualbox) first if you're unsure.

Comment: VM on Windows? And what about the partition issue?

Comment: Windows 10 almost never installs in one partition. With BIOS/MBR it has two, but then adds recovery & vendor recovery to use all 4 primary partitions. With UEFI/gpt it adds ESP - efi system partition and a system reserved partition. Gpt does not have any real partition limit. So is system UEFI or BIOS boot? Hard drive will not be corrupted by more partitions, but you do in Windows 8 or 10 have to turn off Windows fast start up (hibernation).  Post this from terminal in live installer to see partitions: `sudo parted -l` Be sure to only boot in UEFI mode. And with nVidia you may need nomodeset.

Comment: This guide suggests the use of a software Macrium Reflect to handle all the installation. Is it suggested? Please reply. Thanks.
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does support more than three partitions (it did on my Lenovo G70-80); Y-50 could have issues though. That's what can be done:

Have a partition for Ubuntu. This partition uses usually ext3 or ext4 file system (not Windows' NTFS). Ubuntu installation will take care of formatting and what not.

If you do not have an empty partition, shrink a volume (partition) with sufficient free space using Windows Disk Management. Press **Win+X** and then press **K** to launch Disk Management. The space created by shrinking a partition will be marked as **unallocated** (black-colored).

During Ubuntu installation select that unallocated partition (you should know which partition by looking at the partition size) and , when asked, select  *install Ubuntu alongside other Operating Systems* to be able to dual boot. Let us know if it works and if you need more concrete, detailed info.

Comment: This guide suggests the use of a software Macrium Reflect to handle all the installation. Is it suggested? Please reply. Thanks.
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

Answer (score 0):

Your shop keeper was, shall we say, ill-informed. Pre-installed Windows systems typically come with at least three partitions already, and often with four or five. Most of these are usually hidden, in the sense that they don't get drive letters, but they do exist.

For EFI reading, I recommend:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than the preceding one.
- **[The Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)** -- This page is a bit disjointed, but is the most Ubuntu-specific introduction to EFI and its issues.

If you want to read just one page, I'd recommend the second of those, although the third has the advantage (for you) of being more Ubuntu-centric. The first is worth reading for background information; it will help you understand things better and therefore enable you to navigate unexpected problems.

Comment: This guide suggests the use of a software Macrium Reflect to handle all the installation. Is it suggested? Please reply. Thanks.
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

Comment: It's recommended by the author of that guide. I neither recommend it nor recommend against it, because I've never used Macrium Reflect. I can't speak for anybody else.